# Apple Mail Behaviour for Anchors in HTML-Mails

Tags: email, html-email, apple-mail

I am experiencing a weird behavior with Apple Mail. If i define an Anchor and jump to it inside an HTML Mail:

```
<a href="#jump1">Text</a>
<a name="jump1">Jump1</a>
```

Then Apple Mail will only jump to this location when you issue a double-click, rather than a single click. You can even have several seconds difference between the first and second click on the anchor, however it seems Apple Mail requires some kind of focus on the link (first click), bevor the jump works (second click).

I even tried several different types of anchor names, Empty anchors,   Anchors, with Text, "name" not on an anchor but on a h2-tag and such, nothing seems to work with a single click.

```
<a name="jump1"></a>
<a name="jump1">&nbsp;</a>
<a name="jump1">Text</a>
```

Is this some kind of expected behavior? Or what is the expected HTML to make this work with one click?

Comment: MY ANS IS RIGHT PLZZ TRY IT THEN REPLY ME

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known problem](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12591847?messageID=12591847) and as far as I'm aware, there's no available fix.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same subject and found out that there are lot of email client (also lot of webmails) having this issue

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3322/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/